# Custom web pages inside Syteline 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, erp

We currently have an ASP.NET Core/Razor web page in our Syteline system. I was wondering what the limitations for custom web pages in Syteline 8 were. Are you able to use any language you like, or are there problems with certain languages showing in Syteline?

For example, we have an annoying API call that I believe would be easier to handle with Angular 6 observables. Would it be possible to build an Angular 6 app and have it be shown inside Syteline?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a little dated but if you are still using Syteline 8 there are a few options. One: you could use a Web user Control. This allows you to import useful libraries and write javaScript to power them. They can be a bit finicky but integrate directly to Syteline and allow you to interact with controls, pass data to the system and invoke events and handlers. There is also a Browser control that allows you to simply view any page inside the control, it offers less control but is a drag and drop operation. The Web User Control will require some time to implement and some testing to make sure you invoke the control correctly. Hope this helps.